# Authentication using ADAL

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am using below code to authenticate default user in my Azure trial account.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetTokenAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
    {
        string Tenant = "mytest.onmicrosoft.com";
        string Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + Tenant;
        string GatewayLoginUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/something/wsfed";
        string ClientId = "something";
        Uri RedirectUri = new Uri("http://something");

        AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);
        PlatformParameters platformParams = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, null);
        AuthenticationResult result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(GatewayLoginUrl, ClientId, RedirectUri, platformParams);

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

I want to know from where to get these values:

- Tenant
- Authority
- GatewayLoginUrl
- ClientId
- RedirectUri

Is this much code sufficient for user authentication using AD?

Comment: It depends on your [type of application and scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#application-types-and-scenarios). Depending on your app type take a look at one of the samples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-developers-guide)

Comment: @PeterBons As of now I have registered a native app. For this how to get GatewayAccessURL and Redirect?

Comment: For Redirect you can use https://localhost for example as a native app does not need a redirect url. GatewayLoginUrl  is the app id uri that you can find in the properties of the client application

Comment: @PeterBons Can you please submit this as answer? With screenshot of GatewayLoginUrl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of scenario's when it comes to protecting applications using the Azure Active Directory (See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#application-types-and-scenarios)):

> These are the five primary application scenarios supported by Azure AD:
>
> 1. Web Browser to Web Application: A user needs to sign in to a web application that is secured by Azure AD.
> 2. Single Page Application (SPA): A user needs to sign in to a single page application that is secured by Azure AD.
> 3. **Native Application to Web API: A native application that runs on a phone, tablet, or PC needs to authenticate a user to get resources from a web API that is secured by Azure AD.**
> 4. Web Application to Web API: A web application needs to get resources from a web API secured by Azure AD.
> 5. Daemon or Server Application to Web API: A daemon application or a server application with no web user interface needs to get resources from a web API secured by Azure AD.

You mention you have registered a Native Application. I assume you need to authenticate against the Azure Active Directory (AAD from now on) to gain access to a protected web api or web app (scenario #3) so you have to register that one as well.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GetTokenAsync().Wait();
}

static async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
{
    string Tenant = "mytest.onmicrosoft.com";
    string Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + Tenant;
    string GatewayLoginUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/something/wsfed";
    string ClientId = "something";
    Uri RedirectUri = new Uri("http://something");

    AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);
    PlatformParameters platformParams = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, null);
    AuthenticationResult result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(GatewayLoginUrl, ClientId, RedirectUri, platformParams);

    return result.ToString();
}
```

- `Tenant` is the name of the AAD domain, it seems you got that one right
- `Authority` is `"https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + Tenant`, so it seems you got that one right too
- `GatewayLoginUrl` is the App Id Uri of the application that you are protecting
- `ClientId` is the Application Id of the native application
- `RedirectUri` is the Redirect Uri of the native application

**Application to Protect:**

[image]

You get the `GatewayLoginUrl` from here.

**Native Application that accesses the Application to Protect:**

[image]

You get the `ClientId` and `RedirectUri` from here.

**Other references**

You can see a full walkthrough for a native application [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-dotnet)

For a global overview of accessing AAD protected applications using a native app see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#native-application-to-web-api)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I tried on Azure trial account. For my native application, I am not seeing any field: "Application ID Uri".

Comment: That is correct, a native application does not have that property, the registered webapp / api application does. Can you tell me more about this native app of yours. What api does it try to access?

Comment: Another team is developing a WebAPI service for user login. I have to write authentication code. I assume first that user login service needs to be registered in AD. From that I will get AppID Uri. Later my authentication code will validate against that. But we have a Xamarin login form. Do I need to use Native to WebAPI authentication or Web App to Web API authentication?